# `npm run build` is reformatting source files in Cloud Functions project

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tsconfig

In my newly generated Firebase Cloud Functions project, when I run `npm run build` (which is `"build": "tsc",` in the generated package.json "scripts"), the build runs successfully.  But in so doing, it reformats the files in my `src` using rules that clearly are not the same as I have set up for the overall project (VSCode, ESLint, Prettier).

In particular, when I "Format Document" in VSCode which uses Prettier, I have `"bracketSpacing": false` and `"tabWidth": 2` but after running `npm run build` the files in my `src` directory are modified so that spaces exist before and after braces (e.g. in `import` statements) and indent width becomes `4`.

I'm surprised that `tsc` touches the source files at all.  I was under the impression that it would only modify the output/build files.

Is there a `tsconfig.json` setting or something I can enable to have it NOT reformat the source files?

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2021"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I'm using tsc `Version 5.3.3`

Comment: Please edit your question to show specifically how your source files are being modified in a way that's "that clearly are not the same".  There should be enough information in your question that anyone can use to reproduce the results.  This will likely involve showing a complete minimal project configuration and source that's not working the way you expect.